# Define relations between two tables in sqlalchemy so I can query easily

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This question is about sqlalchemy as well as a suitable datastructure.

There is a table with roomtypes like `living_room` every type of room is only listed once.
It can be painted with every color defined in the `colors` table. In this table every color is listed once.
Every `color` has a `price` associated with it.

I want to be able peform a query along the line of

```py
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(engine) as session:
    stmt = select(Room).where(
        Room.room_type == "living_room", Room.color == "green"
    )
    selected_room = session.scalars(stmt).one()
    session.commit()
    selected_room.price == 15
```

With the intent that I query combinations and recieve the price it cost to paint that kind of room.

The folowing is my Declaritive Base without defined relations

```py
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = "rooms"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("room_type"))

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    room_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)

class Color(Base):
    __tablename__ = "colors"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("color"),)

    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    color: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    price: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
```

*The paint / color is an analogy to keep the example simple*

Question 1 : How to define the relationship that every color is suitable to every room.

Question 2 : This can be considered a Many-to-Many relationship, would it then be better to have an accociated table?

Question 3 : Should I do it withouth ORM functionality and use the `Core` instead. (Don't have a clear Idea yet. )

**Relationship**

The `Room` needs it relation defined to `Color`

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Room(Base):
    __tablename__ = "rooms"
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("room_type"))

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    room_type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    color = relationship("Color")
```

To provide some extra context: There is one table which looks like

```py
class Price(Base):
    __tablename__ = "price"
    id:Mapped[int]= mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    article: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    color: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    price: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float)
```

This table contains other types of `article` besides `room` for example `chair`.

My current idea is to cross-join the `rooms` table with the `colors` table and Union those with the `price` table as a view. Which I then can query. I think I am too much on the path of defining relationships when there aren't any.

This would be

```py
# cross join with all possible Room-Color combinations
# cross joins are not supported in SQLAlchemy

with Session(engine) as session:
    stmt = select(Room.__table__, Color.__table__)
    view_stmt = text(f"CREATE VIEW room_color as {str(stmt.compile(engine))}")
    session.execute(view_stmt)
```

Comment: So you need a table with a column "room type" and a column "color"?

Comment: Yes, indeed for all possible combinations.

Comment: Does that answer your questions 1 & 2? Or what is still unclear?

Comment: Are you suggesting to fill a table with all possible combinations? I want to try to set this up dynamically that a new color can be added without a new table to be populated. Or are you suggesting to build a new associated table with `room_type` and `color` and define relationship through that table?

Comment: I'm not sure what "associated" table means, but I suppose the latter. A row in this table means that a room with a particular type and color exists.

Comment: So, is "color" actually an attribute of a "room"?  Or are you trying to ask "what will it cost to paint this living room green?"

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for good clarifying questions. My question is indeed what will it cost to paint this living room green.

Comment: @mkrieger1 so these room / color combinations don't exist and I am also not interested in if they where. Every color is only listed once. I'll expand the post a bit to clarify

Comment: So if you want to query what it would cost to paint a room in a color, you would look up the cost of the color and ignore the room type?!

Comment: Yes the only thing is to know for sure the `room_type` exist but that could then be part of the select_query of course.  
I was thinking that I could create a table where `if room_type exists with color = green` could be created to easy the `select` statement.

Comment: I don't think you should be designing your database based on how you are going to query. `room_type` and `color` are not associated based on your description. Shouldn't a room have a color and that color has a price associated to it? Is the price simply the color or does it depend in the size of the `room_type`?